# Склонение фамилии Штокалец

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли фамилилия Штокалец?

Answer (score 2):

Склонение фамилий на **-ец** зависит от пола лица. Если фамилия относится к мужчине, то она **склоняется** как существительное второго склонения мужского рода.
Женские фамилии такого типа не склоняются.

При склонения мужских фамилий, оканчивающихся на *-ец*, часто возникает вопрос: сохранять ли беглый гласный? Вот что рекомендует [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Вопрос № 292366 (фамилия ***Билец***)
Ответ. Да, склонение обязательно, но возможны варианты: Р., В. – Билеца и Бильца, Д. – Билецу и Бильцу, Т. – Билецем и Бильцем, П. – о Билеце и о Бильце.

Вопрос № 285607 (***Гаврилец***); Вопрос № 284109 (***Михалец***)
Ответ. Возможно склонение мужской фамилии с выпадением гласного (Гаврильца, Гаврильцу; Михальца, Михальцу) и без выпадения гласного (Гаврилеца, Гаврилецу; Михалеца, Михалецу). Второй вариант предпочтителен (ведь фамилии выполняют и юридическую функцию), но окончательное решение – за носителем фамилии.

И. п. (кто?)  Штокалец
Р. п. (кого?) Штокальца; Штокалеца
Д. п. (кому?) Штокальцу; Штокалецу
В. п. (кого?) Штокальца; Штокалеца
Т. п. (кем?)  Штокальцом; Штокалецем
П. п. (о ком?) Штокальце; Штокалеце

Если бы мне пришлось выбирать, я бы (вопреки рекомендациям "Грамоты") выбрала вариант с мягким знаком. Мне он кажется более благозвучным.

[Склонение фамилий на "-ец"](http://semfamily.ru/34)
[Как склонять фамилии (трудные случаи)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482)